# Flutter ListView vs ListView.builder()

Tags: flutter

I understand that listview.builder only renders what is visible on the screen and listview renders everything.

If I set the addAutomaticKeepAlives property of a listview to false, does it have the same effect as listview.builder?

I want to know the difference between
listview.builder
vs
listview (addAutomaticKeepAlives=false)

Answer (score 0):

@cheeezbucket Disabling `addAutomaticKeepAlives` in a `ListView` does not result in the same behavior as `ListView.builder`

**The distinction is as follows:**

`ListView.builder` renders items as needed, conserving memory for large lists. `ListView` with `addAutomaticKeepAlives=false` saves memory by not keeping items' state when off-screen, though it may lead to state loss in some cases.

In conclusion, `ListView.builder` is tailored to efficiently display extensive lists, whereas `ListView` with `addAutomaticKeepAlives=false` can be advantageous in situations where memory conservation is desired for lengthy lists, but `ListView.builder` is not preferred for specific reasons.

I hope this information proves helpful!

Comment: So the addAutomaticKeepAlives property is for when the screen is off?

Comment: No, the addAutomaticKeepAlives property in Flutter's ListView widget is not related to the screen being on or off.

Comment: Setting addAutomaticKeepAlives to false means that the items in the list won't automatically hold onto their state when they go off-screen. This can be useful for conserving memory, especially when dealing with long lists, as it prevents Flutter from keeping all widgets alive and storing their state.

Comment: This answer feels autogenerated, especially with "in conclusion" in such a short set of text.  Flagging for review.

Comment: @WebDeskSolution I still don't understand the difference between .builder() and addAutomaticKeepAlives=false, since .builder doesn't keep offscreen either.